# How do I use RequestHandler to accept data from ajax?

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I try to send data form ajax to cakephp cotroller

```
function loadtooltip(obj, $user_id) {
 //AJAX
 var req = Inint_AJAX();
 req.onreadystatechange = function () { 
      if (req.readyState==4) {
           if (req.status==200) {
                displaytooltip(obj, req.responseText);
           } 
      } 
 };

 req.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1/cakeplate/tooltips/tooltip/", true); 
 req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 req.send($user_id);
```

};

this controller

```
<?php
Class TooltipsController extends AppController{
var $name = 'Tooltips';
var $uses = array('Reply','User');
var $component = array('RequestHandler','Javascript','Ajax');
var $layout =  'tooltip';


function tooltip($user_id=NULL){

                if(!empty($user_id)){
                    $tooltip = $this->Reply->User->findById($user_id);
                    $this->set('tooltip',$tooltip);
                }

}
}
 ?>
```

I need somebody to help me to modified code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way you're doing at the moment in the controller, you won't me able to get the user_id, because it is a var passed through GET method of http.

This variable would be accessible if you make a GET request for example for this url:
**http://example.com/cakeplate/tooltips/tooltip/1** where 1 would be your $user_id.

If you send the request as POST, you can access the values in this var **$this->data**
This way you will be able to process the request based in the var that you pass to the controller.

Another problem that you will face that this controller will need to render a view, so i suggest that you take a look at http://book.cakephp.org/view/1238/REST, there you can see how you can create a route that will make the controller parse another view, it a different custom layout, like the json (the one i suggest in this case), and then you can show in this view only the json value.

Last, but important as well, i would suggest to that you use jQuery to do the javascript part, i think it will be easier, you can check it at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get